# Android Google Maps set marker using GeoJSON

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I wish to use the GeoJSON Marker within my Android application, the symbol more specifically which is illustrated in the code as marker-symbol. Although, I can get the title of each function separately, the marker-symbol does not change and it stays as the red default as shown below. Does anyone know how to change the marker icon?

GeoJSON Marker:

[image]

Normal Default Marker:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the styling function in order to create a custom markers while using GeoJson. Styling function are mostly used to apply styles on a specific feature like marker.

For example this is your Json Data:

```
{
  "type": "MarkerCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Marker",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "icon": "/static/images/icons/map-marker-do.png",
        "coordinates": [
          -10.45893,
          23.8574
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": "Restaurant",
        "description": "Best Restaurant to eat Italian",
        "icon": "/static/images/icons/map-marker-do.png"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The styling code would be:

```
map.data.setStyle(function(marker) {
    return {icon:feature.getProperty('icon')};
  });
```